# DocBook XSL: how do I stop HTML generation from outputting a title attribute?

Tags: docbook

The DocBook XSL's HTML generator always outputs a `title` attribute for `div` sections that come from DocBook elements that have titles. So articles, books, sections, etc all have a `title` attribute.

I don't want this in my HTML. It causes Firefox at least to display a tooltip containing the section's title. That might be useful if I weren't chunking my HTML, but I am, so it is unhelpful. And annoying.

How would I get rid of it? Is there a simple parameter I can set, or do I have to use a customization layer? If the latter, what do I have to catch to prevent it from doing this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no parameter, but you only need to add

```
<xsl:template name="generate.html.title"/>
```

to your customization layer. This overrides the original template (in html.xsl) and disables output of the `title` attributes.